# Import java package from Matlab deploytool to Android Studio App

Tags: java, android, image, matlab, jar

I managed to create a java package from a Matlab function (for image processing) using deploytool. I tested it in Eclipse and it runs perfectly. The problem is that I want to use this Matlab function for an Android Studio project and I can´t find any way to make it work.

As you may know, when you use Matlab´s deploytool for java packages it generates three folders: "for_redistribution" which contains an .exe file (MyAppInstaller_web.exe), "for_redistribution_files_only" that contains the .jar and documentation, and "for_testing" which contains pretty much the same, the .jar file, documentation and java classes

My question is: is it possible to use this in an Android App? And if so, how? And are there any other options (other than using openCV instead of a Matlab function) to make it work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java components that are generated from MATLAB code using `deploytool` (or using other functionality from MATLAB deployment products such as MATLAB Compiler, MATLAB Builder etc.) depend on the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR).

The MCR has much too large a footprint to run on an Android device, and it's really not possible to deploy MATLAB Code to Android in this way.

You have two main options:

1. Use the add-on product MATLAB Coder to convert your MATLAB code to C. This C code does not (unlike the deployment products) depend on the MCR, and be compiled and incorporated into your Android app like other C code.
2. Deploy your java component as a web service, and have your Android app communicate with it remotely.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer... I thought about developing a web service, as you said, but I would never come up with your first idea, so thank you so much for your answer!